# Change Image according width of control

Tags: grid, silverlight-5.0, gridsplitter

i have a one image control in grid and one grid splitter in the grid also one `List<imgobject>`, imgobject contains 3 images img48, img32, img24 how can i change the image according to with of grid cell,`List<imgobject>` is bind with on stack panel which is inside the grid cell

```
width >= 100 then 64
Width <= 70 and >= 50 then 32 
else 24
```

When i move gridsplite left side then grid cell width was change according to spliter movement at that time wants to change image in image control

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking how to load images dynamically at runtime?  If so, here is how I do it:

```
img = New Image
img.Source = New Imaging.BitmapImage(New Uri("/APPNAME;component/Images/home.png", UriKind.Relative))
```

APPNAME = the name of your application.
Images = the folder name I keep my images in
Home.png = the file I want to load

Comment: No - image was load was done. my question is i want to change image according to with of grid column

Comment: What do you mean by "change image"?